# Iron Router routing entry data retrieval function run twice

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'm new to `Meteor` (and full stack JS development for that matter) and experimenting a bit trying to convert an app I currently have running on Google App Engine in Django/Python.

I have the following route entry using `Iron Router`:

```
this.route("editFacility", {
  path: "/facilities/:_id/edit",
  template: "editFacility",
  data: function() {
    return Facilities.findOne({ _id: this.params._id });
  }
});
```

... and the following template (using autoform's quickform):

```
<template name="editFacility">
  <h2>Edit facility "{{description}}"</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      {{> quickForm
        collection="Facilities"
        omitFields="createdAt, updatedAt"
        doc=this
        id="updateFacilityForm"
        type="update"
        template="bootstrap3-horizontal"
        label-class="col-sm-2"
        input-col-class="col-sm-6"}}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

The route gets triggered by:

```
{{#linkTo route='editFacility' _id=this._id class="btn btn-default btn-xs"}}Edit{{/linkTo}}
```

Initially it looked like the form wasn't filled with data, but putting a `debugger` statement in the route's `data:` function revealed that this function is actually ran twice. The first time finding the document and correctly filling the form, immediately followed by a second time and failing the find thus clearing the form. The stack doesn't reveal any particulars and looks identical for both runs:

[image]

I googled the issue and found some references but none with a clear solution. I've updated `meteor` and all my packages to the latest & greatest but this issue persists.

So my question, what causes `meteor` / `Iron Router` to execute this route entry twice?

Comment: Please read up about reactivity in meteor. The `findOne` call is reactive, so when the data in the collection changes it is rerun. No idea why the data would disappear in the collection (usually it is the other way round, first empty then not), but this definitely sounds like a reactive re-run.

Comment: yes, usually it's other way around. do you have the proper subscription that populates the form data?

Comment: @ChristianFritz I've read about reactivity. There has been no data change in the collection other than the first successful find of the document (if that qualifies as a "change"). The second find, with an identical context and document id fails and blanks out the form. I'm puzzled...

Comment: @FaysalAhmed I'm running this app in prototype mode, so with the insecure package installed. I was under the impression that I do not need subscriptions until I remove the insecure package.

Comment: autopublish ensures the subscription. btw, do the problem still not resolved? if not you can share more snippet in meteor enthusiast chat group.

Comment: @FaysalAhmed Ah... autopublish, that was the one causing this. Apparently I had removed that package without fully grasping the consequences. After re-adding autopublish the problem was solved. Cheers for your help. If you want you can leave an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are missing the package `autopublish` from your package list. It's responsible for publishing every data available in the server. Otherwise you need to write a publication and then subscribe it back in the client.